# How to solve UnsupportedMediatType when using RestSharp and OAuth2

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, restsharp

Just a few minutes ago I managed to make my code work with `RestSharp` and `OAuth2`, retrieving an access token. I now want to use that token on every call that I make to my REST API. Unfortunately I keep getting an `UnsupportedMediaType` `StatusCode` although the response status is completed.

Here is my code when I make that request:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/myapi/products/get");
client.Proxy = proxy;

RestRequest request = new RestRequest( ) { Method = Method.POST };
request.AddParameter("application/json", String.Format( "{{\"email\": \"{0}\", \"key\": \"{1}\"}}", email, key ), ParameterType.RequestBody);

request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");     

request.AddParameter("access_token",APIAuthenticator.Instance().GetAccessToken(proxy));

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

The `APIAuthenticator.Instance().GetAccessToken(proxy)` works fine and simply gets the access token. So what can the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you're doing here

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", 
    String.Format( "{{\"email\": \"{0}\", \"key\": \"{1}\"}}", email, key ), 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
request.AddParameter("access_token",APIAuthenticator.Instance().GetAccessToken(proxy));
```

First you set the body to your JSON with the `application/json` Content-Type. A request can only have one body. What you are doing with the last two lines is overriding the original. You set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set the body to the access token.

Most likely the reason you're getting a 415 unsupported media type is because the resource endpoint is expecting data (your JSON) as `application/json`. It doesn't support the type you overrode it with. Event if it did, you're still sending the wrong data (your access token).

So how do you send the access token? It might be possible to send it in the query string (depending on the auth server configuration), i.e.

```
.../myapi/products/get?access_token=yourAccessToken
```

but this is more used with the [Implicit Grant Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2).

The more common way is to send the token in the `Authorization` header as seen [here in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7.1), e.g.

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

Now this depends on the configured profiles in the auth server, but for the most part, Bearer should be accepted.

Then just get rid of

```
//request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//request.AddParameter("access_token",APIAuthenticator.Instance().GetAccessToken(proxy));
```

Comment: Once again many thanks. What you 've given me works like a dream.